# Is there a way to set the compatibility mode in Win7 programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, themes, compatibility

I am working on a program. In testing it on Win7(32-bit, don't know if it will be the same in 64-bit) I found a problem.

Now my problem is that some of the functionality does not work(like the right click doesn't show options or the program takes long to react). If however I set up a the compatibility mode it works fine. I mainly see this problem in Microstation, but it does appear in other places as well.

**My question is as follows, is there a way to set these settings(like the check boxes) programmatically from C# ?**

This might be necessary in cases where we do not do the installation of the program, to insure that it works on every pc it is installed on.  Let us assume that during the installation the program has admin rights. (**would it be needed to do this??**)

this has nothing to do with Internet Explorer. i wanted to add a picture, but i dont have enough rep yet

Comment: You [don't do that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/11/9976571.aspx).

Comment: Please don't demand admin rights to run or install your app. Find and fix the problem that is prompting the switch to compat mode, don't just put a bandaid over a gunshot.

Comment: If you are developing the program then simply fix the bugs. Compatibility mode is for old programs that you can't modify.

Comment: @Beska I'm not sure if it is in accordance with the rules, and I also didn't downvote, but maybe it is used as a strong sign for "This is a really bad idea".

Comment: ok, i see that it isn't the best option. the problem is that we already have the app out at clients. and it sucks, but we are not given time now to fix that. so yes, this is a band aid FOR SURE, and we will fix it, but for now, it would be nice to have a "quick fix"

Comment: @asawyer we have to use admin. there are some components that need to be registered, etc.(wont go into too much detail). so yes, we do have admin rights (don't worry, its not an app that you are likely to run across.hehehe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change this while the application is running, you have two choices to handle this issue:

- Modify the installer to create shortcuts that have the compatibility mode flag set to whatever you need
- You can manually manipulate the registry to force an executable to use compatibility mode, your application will require admin rights todo so + will need to restart afterwards
  Here it's explained how todo it manually, you simply have to do it programatically:
  http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/139/

**In general I discourage you from doing either, fix your bugs instead.**

Comment: 1) how would i do the 1st one?

Comment: 2) like i commented above. this will be a band aid. we dont have time just now to find the problem, but will fix it later. any idea where to look for something like this(like where the bug could come from)?

Comment: @MaNTiS You need the Application Compatibility Toolkit.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7352